# Submit Form in HTML/PHP/MySQL from one Document and Display Results in another Document

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, forms, http-post

I have created an HTML `<form>` powered by PHP/MySQL, which allows users to input some information and then (should) send/store the inputted data upon submitting the `<form>` via `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />`. The `<form>` (should) connect and store the user inputted date through PHP, into a MySQL database. PHP then powers the response that is displayed on a results page that is different from the page that the HTML `<form>` is on.

Here's the last point I came to without any errors, but also not achieving the desired solution of displaying the results page on another page:

HTML `<form>`:

```
<form action="pdotest/test.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="firstname">Input 1: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /></label>
    <label for="lastname">Input 2: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" /></label>
    <label for="email">Input 3: <input type="text" name="email" /></label>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP/MySQL Processing:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Results Page:

```
<?php

echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I'm wondering what I put in for the values for: VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')"; to make it process. I'm assuming something along the lines of "echo $_POST['firstname'];"?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out.

Comment: Care to add an answer for the future readers who happen upon this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not clear what is being asked. Also, user found a solution, but as of yet has not answered/editing question/answer, providing the community with the solution.